# React Native Image Upload with FormData to NestJS server using a FileInterceptor, but 'file' is undefined

Tags: react-native, file-upload, nestjs, multer, form-data

My React Native application receives a selected image using the `react-native-image-picker` library and I need to send that image to a back-end running a NestJS server. The endpoint uses `@UseInterceptor` and `FileInterceptor` to extract the image from the 'file' field of the formData received. However, when I fire the request to the endpoint, the file received is undefined.

Here is my React Native code sending the request with the file in the FormData as a payload.

```
const uploadNewProfileImage = async () => {
    if (!newProfileImage?.assets) return;
    const formData = new FormData();
    const profileImage = newProfileImage.assets[0];
    console.log(profileImage);
    if (profileImage.uri && user) {
      formData.append(
        'file',
        JSON.stringify({
          uri:
            Platform.OS === 'android'
              ? profileImage.uri
              : profileImage.uri.replace('file://', ''),
          name: profileImage.fileName,
          type: profileImage.type
        })
      );
      client // client is an Axios instance that injects Bearer Token
        .post(`/user/profile/${user.uid}/image`, formData)
        .then(({ data }) => {
          console.log(data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err.response);
          setShowImageUploadError(true);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          getUserProfile();
        });
    }
  };
```

Here is my back-end NestJS code extracting the file.

```
// User.controller.ts
@UseGuards(UserGuard)
@ApiBearerAuth()
@ApiUnauthorizedResponse({ description: 'Unauthorized' })
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file', { limits: { fileSize: 20000000 } }))
@Post('/profile/:uid/image')
@ApiOkResponse({ type: UploadProfileResponse })
@ApiBadRequestResponse({ description: 'Image too large OR Invalid image type' })
async uploadProfilePicture(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File, @Request() req): Promise<UploadProfileResponse> {
    const uid = req.user.uid;
    const imageUrl = await this.userService.uploadProfilePicture(uid, file);
    return imageUrl;
  }
}
```

I tried to set the axios request header in the axios config like so

```
{
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=——file'
  }
}
```

I tried chaning the back-end endpoint to the following

```
@UseGuards(UserGuard)
@ApiBearerAuth()
@ApiUnauthorizedResponse({ description: 'Unauthorized' })
@UseInterceptors(FileFieldsInterceptor([{ name: 'file' }], { limits: { fileSize: 20000000 } }))
@Post('/profile/:uid/image')
@ApiOkResponse({ type: UploadProfileResponse })
@ApiBadRequestResponse({ description: 'Image too large OR Invalid image type' })
async uploadProfilePicture(@UploadedFiles() file: Array<Express.Multer.File>, @Request() req): Promise<UploadProfileResponse> {
  const uid = req.user.uid;
  console.log("File", file);
  const imageUrl = await this.userService.uploadProfilePicture(uid, file[0]);
  return imageUrl;
}
```

Nothing seems to be working, and the file extracted from the backend is still undefined.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe remove `JSON.stringify` when appending the formaData

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you and I took me days to fix it. It turned out that when you read image using `react-native-image-picker`, the `fileName` field is `null`.

```
The image is:  {"assetId": null, "base64": null, "duration": null, "exif": null, 
"fileName": null, "fileSize": 282352, "height": 1472, "type": "image", 
"uri": "file:///..../ImagePicker/73C6B334-2F8F-4588-92FA-C83E11B76B74.png", 
"width": 2456}
```

So you just need to fix a name for the uploaded image:

```
  formData.append('file', {
    uri: profileImage.uri,
    type: profileImage.type,
    name: 'image.jpg',
  });
```

And you **do not** need to `stringify` when appending the data as well as transform the URL like this:

```
uri:
        Platform.OS === 'android'
          ? profileImage.uri
          : profileImage.uri.replace('file://', ''),
```